# Транспонировать матрицу, разбив на блоки

Tags: c, матрицы, преобразование

Требуется ускорить транспонирование большой матрицы, элементы размещены в памяти последовательно.
Ускорить нужно за счет обработки матрицы блоками, чтобы из кэша необходимые куски памяти не успевали стираться.

Проблема возникла в написании кода самого транспонирования - выполнение затыкается и ничего не работает.
Ниже сам кусок кода

```
void transposematrixblocked(int **src, int **dst, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i + BLOCKSIZE) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j + BLOCKSIZE) {
      for (int ini = 0; ini < BLOCKSIZE; ini ++) {
        for (int inj = 0; inj < BLOCKSIZE; inj ++) {
            dst[i+ini][j+inj] = src[j+inj][i+ini];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

где я оплошала и как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле for 3-й параметр должен быть вида `i += BLOCKSIZE`

```
void transposematrixblocked(int **src, int **dst, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += BLOCKSIZE) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j += BLOCKSIZE) {
      for (int ini = 0; ini < BLOCKSIZE; ini ++) {
        for (int inj = 0; inj < BLOCKSIZE; inj ++) {
            dst[i+ini][j+inj] = src[j+inj][i+ini];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Основная ошибка действительно была в синтаксисе - `i + BLOCKSIZE`, вместо `i += BLOCKSIZE`.

Итоговый работающий код ниже:

```
/* Transpose the blocked square matrix src and put the result in dst */
void transposematrixblocked(int **src, int **dst, int size) {

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += BLOCKSIZE) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j += BLOCKSIZE) {
      for (int ini = i; ini < i + BLOCKSIZE; ini ++) {
        for (int inj = j; inj < j + BLOCKSIZE; inj ++) {
            dst[ini][inj] = src[inj][ini];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```